# Code Design: JSON from Socket to custom handler class

Tags: java, json, generics, gson, guice

I have an Socket-Server in Java. This socket will receive json-strings with an specific structure.

```
{
    "command": "test",
    "name": "Hallo Welt"
}
```

I can not change this structure. The value of "command" will declare the type of content.

After I receive this from the socket, I would like to call different handlers, to handle these different commands:

- command "test" > TestHandler implements CommandHandler
- command "foo" > FooHandler implements CommandHandler

**How can I  convert the json into a object and bind the object to the specific handler?**

This is my current approach:
I have an model class called BaseCommand which contains a enum command field.

```
class BaseCommand {
    public CommandType command;
}

class TestCommand extends BaseCommand {
    public String name;
}
```

With GSON I parse the JSON to BaseCommand class. 
After that I can read the command type.

I declare a ENUM to map the command types to the Handler:

```
enum CommandType {
    test(TestHandler.class),
    foo(FooHandler.class);

    public final Class<? extends CommandHandler> handlerClass;        

    public CommandTypes(Class<? extends CommandHandler> handlerClass) {
        this.handlerClass = handlerClass;
    }
}
```

My handler's are implementing this interface:

```
public interface CommandHandler<T extends BaseCommand> {
    void handle(T command);
}
```

Now I have the command type enum and through Google Guices [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) I can get the Handler instance to handle request. This works

```
// in class ...
private final Map<CommandType, CommandHandler> handlers;

@Inject ClassName(Map<CommandType, CommandHandler> handlers) {
    this.handlers = handlers;
}

// in converter method
private void convert(String json) {
    BaseCommand baseCommand = GSONHelper().fromJson(json, BaseCommand.class);

    // How can I get the CommandModel? 
    // If the commandType is "test" how can I parse TestCommand automatically?

    ??? commandModel = GSONHelper().fromJson(json, ???);

    handlers.get(baseCommand.command).handle(commandModel);
}
```

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?
Or a complete different approach for this?

best regards, Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the CommandModel?
>   If the commandType is "test" how can I parse TestCommand automatically?

You can use a `TypeAdapterFactory` to get the most appropriate type adapter in the most accurate and flexible way. The example below slightly differs from your classes naming, but I think it's not a big issue to you. So, let's assume you have the following command arguments DTO declarations:

```java
abstract class AbstractCommandDto {

    final String command = null;

}
```

```java
final class HelloCommandDto
        extends AbstractCommandDto {

    final String name = null;

}
```

Now you can make a special `TypeAdapterFactory` to make a sort of looking-ahead to determine the incoming command by command arguments name. It may look complicated, but in fact `TypeAdapterFactory`ies are not that hard to implement. Note that `JsonDeserializer` might be another option for you, but then you lose automatic deserializing unless you delegate its `deserialize()` method to another backing `Gson` instance.

```java
final class AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // The factory handles no state and can be instantiated once    
    private static final TypeAdapterFactory abstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory = new AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory();

    // Type tokens are used to define type information and are perfect value types so they can be instantiated once as well
    private static final TypeToken<CommandProbingDto> abstractCommandProbingDtoTypeToken = new TypeToken<CommandProbingDto>() {
    };

    private static final TypeToken<HelloCommandDto> helloCommandDtoTypeToken = new TypeToken<HelloCommandDto>() {
    };

    private AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getAbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return abstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // First, check if the incoming type is AbstractCommandDto
        if ( AbstractCommandDto.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // If yes, then build a special type adapter for the concrete type
            final TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto> abstractCommandDtoTypeAdapter = new AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapter(
                    gson,
                    gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, abstractCommandProbingDtoTypeToken),
                    (commandName, jsonObject) -> deserialize(gson, commandName, jsonObject),
                    dto -> getTypeAdapter(gson, dto)
            );
            // Some cheating for javac...
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) abstractCommandDtoTypeAdapter;
            return typeAdapter;
        }
        // If it's something else, just let Gson pick up the next type adapter
        return null;
    }

    // Create an AbstractCommandDto instance out of a ready to use JsonObject (see the disadvantages about JSON trees below)
    private AbstractCommandDto deserialize(final Gson gson, final String commandName, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeToken<AbstractCommandDto> typeToken = (TypeToken<AbstractCommandDto>) resolve(commandName);
        final TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto> typeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        return typeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonObject);
    }

    private TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto> getTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final AbstractCommandDto dto) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Class<AbstractCommandDto> clazz = (Class<AbstractCommandDto>) dto.getClass();
        return gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(clazz));
    }

    // Or any other way to resolve the class. This is just for simplicity and can be even extract elsewhere from the type adapter factory class
    private static TypeToken<? extends AbstractCommandDto> resolve(final String commandName)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        switch ( commandName ) {
        case "hello":
            return helloCommandDtoTypeToken;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle " + commandName);
        }
    }

    private static final class AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapter
            extends TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto> {

        private final Gson gson;
        private final TypeAdapter<CommandProbingDto> probingTypeAdapter;
        private final BiFunction<? super String, ? super JsonObject, ? extends AbstractCommandDto> commandNameToCommand;
        private final Function<? super AbstractCommandDto, ? extends TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto>> commandToTypeAdapter;

        private AbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapter(
                final Gson gson,
                final TypeAdapter<CommandProbingDto> probingTypeAdapter,
                final BiFunction<? super String, ? super JsonObject, ? extends AbstractCommandDto> commandNameToCommand,
                final Function<? super AbstractCommandDto, ? extends TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto>> commandToTypeAdapter
        ) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.probingTypeAdapter = probingTypeAdapter;
            this.commandNameToCommand = commandNameToCommand;
            this.commandToTypeAdapter = commandToTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final AbstractCommandDto dto)
                throws IOException {
            // Just pick up a delegated type adapter factory and use it
            // Or just throw an UnsupportedOperationException if you're not going to serialize command arguments
            final TypeAdapter<AbstractCommandDto> typeAdapter = commandToTypeAdapter.apply(dto);
            typeAdapter.write(out, dto);
        }

        @Override
        public AbstractCommandDto read(final JsonReader in) {
            // Here you can two ways:
            // * Either "cache" the whole JSON tree into memory (JsonElement, etc,) and simplify the command peeking
            // * Or analyze the JSON token stream in a more efficient and sophisticated way
            final JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(in, JsonObject.class);
            final CommandProbingDto commandProbingDto = probingTypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonObject);
            // Or just jsonObject.get("command") and even throw abstractCommandDto, AbstractCommandProbingDto and all of it gets away
            final String commandName = commandProbingDto.command;
            return commandNameToCommand.apply(commandName, jsonObject);
        }

    }

    // A synthetic class just to obtain the command field
    // Gson cannot instantiate abstract classes like what AbstractCommandDto is 
    private static final class CommandProbingDto
            extends AbstractCommandDto {
    }

}
```

And how it's used:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    // Build a command DTO-aware Gson instance
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getAbstractCommandDtoTypeAdapterFactory())
            .create();
    // Build command registry
    final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> commandRegistry = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    commandRegistry.put(HelloCommandDto.class, new HelloCommand());
    // Simulate and accept a request
    final AbstractCommandDto abstractCommandDto = gson.fromJson("{\"command\":\"hello\",\"name\":\"Welt\"}", AbstractCommandDto.class);
    // Resolve a command
    final Consumer<?> command = commandRegistry.get(abstractCommandDto.getClass());
    if ( command == null ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot handle " + abstractCommandDto.command);
    }
    // Dispatch
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Consumer<AbstractCommandDto> castCommand = (Consumer<AbstractCommandDto>) command;
    castCommand.accept(abstractCommandDto);
    // Simulate a response
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(abstractCommandDto));
}

private static final class HelloCommand
        implements Consumer<HelloCommandDto> {

    @Override
    public void accept(final HelloCommandDto helloCommandDto) {
        System.out.println("Hallo " + helloCommandDto.name);
    }

}
```

The output:

> Hallo Welt